# How to find a limit in implicit function

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, implicit-function-theorem

I have a function of the form as follows
$$
a \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-(p(x)/(p(x)+a))^N}dx=A
$$
In the function, $p(x)$ is a known function between $[p_0,1]\subset [0,1]$. $A$ is a positive constant.

Thus, the equation actually describes relationship between $a$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$. I have already shown that $a>0$ is increasing in $N$ by implicit function theorem. My question is, how can I find the limit of $a$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$?

It seems obvious that if let $\lim_N a$ be finite, then what's in the integral is always equal to one as $N$ goes to infinity. Then we get $\lim_N a=A$, which is also finite. But I don't know how to show the result in a rigorous way? Or, I was wrong about it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that
$A
> a
> A-\frac1{N}\int_0^1 p(x)dx
$,
so
$\lim_{N \to \infty} a
=A
$.

First of all,
$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-(p(x)/(p(x)+a))^N}dx
> 1$,
so
$A > a$.

Then,
using Bernoulli's inequality,

$\begin{array}\\
(p(x)+a)/p(x)
&=1+(a/p(x))\\
\text{so}\\
((p(x)+a)/p(x))^N
&=(1+(a/p(x)))^N\\
&>1 + Na/p(x)\\
\text{or}\\
(p(x)/(p(x)+a))^N
&<1/(1 + Na/p(x))\\
&=p(x)/(p(x) + Na)\\
\text{Therefore}\\
1-(p(x)/(p(x)+a))^N
&>1-(p(x)+Na)/p(x)\\
&=Na/(p(x) + Na)\\
\text{so that}\\
A
&=a \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-(p(x)/(p(x)+a))^N}dx\\
&<a\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(Na)/(p(x) + Na)}\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{(p(x) + Na)dx}{N}\\
&=\frac1{N}\int_0^1 p(x)dx+a\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$A
> a
> A-\frac1{N}\int_0^1 p(x)dx
$,
so
$\lim_{N \to \infty} a
=A
$.